# C# Json deserialization error

Tags: c#, json, datatable, deserialization, multi-level

I want to convert json string to C# datatable and my json string contains another json string.
I don't want to convert internal json string (keep it as string only). this is my code

```
 string js = "[{\"FirstName\":\"first\",\"LastName\":\"second\",\"jsonStr\":\"[{\"abc\":\"a\",\"xyz\":\"x\"}]\"}]";
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(js, (typeof(DataTable)));
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
```

But I am getting an error

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: a. Path
>   '[0].jsonStr', line 1, position 56.

Comment: Note sure if you json even valid? I just pasted it in an online parse and it shows errors with you json. Second of all I am no sure if Json Converter are aware how to create a database out of Json. You may need to parse json to an object, then from object create your datatable by defining columns and rows.

Comment: put in some new lines in the string `\r\n`, it's easier to count the lines than characters

Comment: please accept an answer. it'll useful for others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. After unescaping, it becomes the following string:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName" : "first",
        "LastName" : "second",
        "jsonStr" : "[{" abc ":" a "," xyz ":" x "}]"
    }
]
```

Stack Overflow syntax highlighting suggests that your JSON is invalid.
You can also check the JSON validity [here](http://jsonlint.com).

In order to make it valid, your quotes within `jsonStr` should have been escaped again:

```
string js = "[{\"FirstName\":\"first\",\"LastName\":\"second\",\"jsonStr\":\"[{\\\"abc\\\":\\\"a\\\",\\\"xyz\\\":\\\"x\\\"}]\"}]";
```

This C# string now contains the following JSON, which is valid:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "first",
        "LastName": "second",
        "jsonStr": "[{\"abc\":\"a\",\"xyz\":\"x\"}]"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't noticed that.